# Dart 3 syntax is not supported on Android Studio

Tags: flutter, android-studio, dart, dart3

How do I fix Android Studio not doing Code Suggestions, Syntax Highlighting or any of the Dart Plugin expected functionality when I write Dart 3 code?

**Android Studio Data:**

Android Studio Bumblebee | 2021.1.1 Patch 1
Build #AI-211.7628.21.2111.8139111, built on February 1, 2022
Runtime version: 11.0.11+9-b60-7590822 amd64
VM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM by Oracle Corporation
Windows 10 10.0
GC: G1 Young Generation, G1 Old Generation
Memory: 1280M
Cores: 6
Registry: external.system.auto.import.disabled=true

**Non-Bundled Plugins:**
Batch Scripts Support (1.0.13), CMD Support (1.0.5), Statistic (4.1.10), com.gionchat (1.3.5), com.bloc.intellij_generator_plugin (3.4.0), com.herbert.george.dart.extensions (0.0.1+3), com.herbert.george.flutter-snippets (2.1.1-stable-1), com.mallowigi (36.0), de.tyxar.clean_architecture_plugin (1.1.0), idea.plugin.protoeditor (2.3.1), com.almightyalpaca.intellij.plugins.discord (1.10.0), Dart (211.7817), com.ixigua.flutter_asset_iteral (1.7.7), com.localizely.flutter-intl (1.18.2-2020.3), com.shenyong.flutter.refgenerator (1.2.221), org.jetbrains.kotlin (211-1.6.21-release-334-AS7442.40), io.flutter (71.2.1), pl.pszklarska.pubversionchecker (1.3.5), org.intellij.plugins.markdown (211.7142.37)

**Flutter Doctor Logs**

```
    [√] Flutter (Channel master, 3.12.0-3.0.pre.67, on Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.19045.2965], locale en-US)
    [√] Windows Version (Installed version of Windows is version 10 or higher)
    [√] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 32.1.0-rc1)
    [√] Chrome - develop for the web
    [√] Visual Studio - develop Windows apps (Visual Studio Community 2022 17.4.3)
    [√] Android Studio (version 2021.1)
    [√] Android Studio (version 2021.3)
    [√] Android Studio (version 2022.1)
    [√] IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition (version 2022.2)
    [√] VS Code (version 1.79.0)
    [√] Connected device (3 available)
    [√] Network resources
```

**Flutter Upgrade Results:**

```
Downloading Dart SDK from Flutter engine effea50196ca4ee957b24d37c3e6766654bde549...
Expanding downloaded archive...
Building flutter tool...
Running pub upgrade...
Resolving dependencies... (5.9s)
Got dependencies.
Flutter is already up to date on channel master
Flutter 3.12.0-3.0.pre.67 • channel master • https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git
Framework • revision 4f94dee851 (83 minutes ago) • 2023-06-12 01:57:26 -0400
Engine • revision effea50196
Tools • Dart 3.1.0 (build 3.1.0-197.0.dev) • DevTools 2.24.0
```

[image]

Comment: Did you update the Dart SDK version to 3.0.0 in your `pubspec.yaml`.

Comment: I did
environment:
  sdk: '>=3.1.0-155.0.dev <4.0.0'

Comment: It works on my machine with Android studio 2023.1, Dart plugin 231.9065, and flutter plugin 74.0.4 (easy to check with `flutter doctor --verbose`).

Comment: Thanks! The problem was with the version of android studio

Answer (score 1):

**FIX** The reason was me using Android Studio 2021 Bumblebee. To fix the problem you need to update to the latest version